# How to uninstall terraform and install newer version of terraform on windows 10 linux subsystem?

Tags: linux, terraform

i want to install a newer version of terrafrom 0.12.24 on windows 10 linux subsystem. i am new to using this interface and i am not sure how to do it

i installed terraform on Windows 10 linux subsystem using these commands

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.13/terraform_0.11.13_linux_amd64.zip -O 
terraform.zip; 
unzip terraform.zip; 
sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin; 
rm terraform.zip;
```

however  this installed older version.. and when i ran some script it gave me this error.

> Failed to load root config module: Error parsing terraform/local/terraform.tf: At 119:12: Unknown token: 119:12 IDENT file

To fix this i am planning to upgrade to newer version of terrafrom 0.12.24. could someone provide me with commands to uninstall and install newer version of terraform thanks.

Comment: Your question and error message has no correlation. You have an issue with Terraform configuration, not with terraform installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should install 0.12.24 version

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.24/terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip
unzip terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip
sudo mv terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64 /usr/local/bin
rm terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64.zip
```

Let me explain what these steps are:

1) The link given along with wget is the downloadable link for the required package. wget helps in downloading it. I changed the version here as your required version.

2) unzip it

3) moved to /usr/local/bin folder.

4) Removing the zip as we have already copied the contents to bin folder

Comment: thanks i was thinking to cleanup previous (older version of terraform) too. just deleting the terraform folder in /usr/local/bin helps?

Comment: yes. As you haven't installed anything. Just copied the contents. Delete that folder and do these steps

Comment: Pls see the edits, the name of the downloaded zip will be terraform_0.12.24_linux_amd64. So I have updated the commands for it @someuser2491

Comment: Please accept the answer if I was of any help. Happy coding. @someuser2491

Answer (score 7):

This is probably more appropriate as a comment but I do not yet have the reputation to do that. As of version 0.15.1, it unzipped only as "terraform", so line 3 in the above answer could just be:

```
sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin
```

And this worked for me.