# How to completely uninstall terraform v0.11.14 from ubuntu 18?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I want to completely remove terraform v0.11.14 from my ubuntu 18 and install the new version. I'm  unable to find any document or articles on web about this..

Comment: It's just a static Go binary. Delete the binary or remove it from your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to uninstall terraform and install newer version of terraform on windows 10 linux subsystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056275/how-to-uninstall-terraform-and-install-newer-version-of-terraform-on-windows-10)

To install it you typically copy the binary to /usr/local/bin, so to uninstall it just delete the binary from the installation location. If you don't know the the location, just run 'which terraform' to find it.